# Work problem in calculus

Tags: calculus

As a water tank is being raised, water spills out at a constant rate of 2 $ft^3$ per foot of rise. If the weight of the tank is 200 lb and it originally contains 1000 $ft^3$ of water, find the work done in raising the tank 20ft.

My initial solution is this:
$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{20}(weight_{tank}+(weight_{water}-2n))(n)}{20}$$

I feel like there's something missing here. I was visualizing that the graph of thisproblem is a linear downward slope one and I need to use an integral to find the total work. Not to mention, this problem was given in a calculus class. So I think a dx appearing in the equation is a must.

Any help would be appreciated and, if possible, could you explain why my initial solution is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You are treating it as if at the end of every foot of rise, $2$ cubic feet of water spill out all at once, but what the problem means is that the water is always spilling out, at a constant rate, amounting to $2$ cubic feet per foot of rise.  If $h$ is the distance of the tank from the ground, and $V$ is the volume of water, then $\frac{dV}{dh}=-2$ if $V$ is measured in ft$^3$ and $h$ is measured in feet.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this fast solution:
first observe the initial conditions:
mass is not constant, **d** stands for waters density
$$ Initial\space volume: V_0=1000 ft,\space Rate\space of\space change\space of\space volume\space per\space ft:\Delta v= 2\space \frac{ft^3}{ft}.$$
$$ then: m_0=\frac{V_0}{d}+m_{tank},\\ \Delta m=\frac{2}{d}$$
given the initial mass, then expressing the mass as a function of height:
$$m=\space(m_0-\frac{2x}{d})$$
then force is:
$$f=ma =(m_0-\frac{2x}{d})\cdot g$$
use definition of work:
$$W=\int_0^{20}fdx = \int_0^{20}(m_0-\frac{2x}{d})\cdot gdx$$

Answer (score 0):

You're treating it as a discrete interval problem, when it's actually meant to be treated in a continuous fashion.

First, if you let $x$ be the height above ground at an instant, you can solve $\frac{dV}{dx} = -2$ to find $V$ in terms of $x$.

Subsequently, to find the work done use $dW = Fdx$, where the force $F = (m+M)g$.

$m$ is the fixed mass of the tank while $M$ is the varying mass of the water. You'll need to introduce a constant to stand for the density of water so you can express $M$ in terms of $V$. I hope you can complete the rest.